# json.org xml generator creates incorrect array output

Tags: java, xml, arrays, json

I'm using the json.org XML.toString() method to create XML from JSON data. This method takes a JSONObject argument and creates an equivalent XML structure, but I'm getting results I don't expect when an array in involved.

This code shows the problem:

```
String jsonString = "{ \"group\" : [ { \"a\" : { } }, {\"a\" : { } } ] }";
System.out.println(XML.toString(new JSONObject(jsonString)));
```

produces:

```
<group><a></a></group><group><a></a></group>
```

whereas I'm expecting:

```
<group><a></a><a></a></group>
```

That is, I expect a single "group" element, not one for each element "a".

I've used online validators to check that the JSON is valid. Am I misunderstanding something, doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Duh...I originally missed the important line of code (XML.toString) - perhaps now the question makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be what you expect, because the object inside the array called `"group"` could contain other values besides `"a"`. For instance, if the JSON was instead

```
{ "group" : [ { "a" : { }, "b" : { } }, {"a" : { }, "b" : { } } ] }
```

your scheme would have produced

```
<group><a></a><b></b><a></a><b></b></group>
```

without any separation between the two pairs of `"a"` and `"b"`.

Comment: Well, that's true, but my expectation is based on my example, not yours. In any case, the issue is why the XML has more than one group. I could have made this clearer.

Comment: A rule has to work for *all* cases. I was showing you how your selection of a simple example obscured a problem that shows up in a more complex one. It's like you asked why all vegetables are sour; I say "no they aren't, carrot is sweet", then you complain because it's actually rhubarb you were thinking of and how dare I bring up carrots. XML has more than one group because that is the way XML normally handles arrays: by repeating elements of the same kind.

Comment: thanks - you're right of course. I just wasn't thinking enough about your answer. My thinking was clouded because in my use of JSON I always use homogeneous arrays.